# improper data formatting - saving query from BigQuery to GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

wondering if someone can help with that.

I have cloud function with python code that does query BigQuery table and stores query result in GCS bucket as csv file.

But in csv file I have got strange format like:

```
Row(('asser',), {'user_login': 0})
Row(('godx',), {'user_login': 0})
Row(('johnw',), {'user_login': 0})
Row(('miki',), {'user_login': 0})
```

But save data format is expexcted to be like:

```
asser,
godx,
johnw,
miki
```

When I do debug in GCP logging console I able to get expected format. Seems I do smth wrong when processing query result.

I use this code:

```
def main(event, context):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    from google.cloud import storage
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime

    project_name = my_project
    destination_bucket = my_bucket

    bq_dataset_name = my_dataset
    bq_table_name = my_table
    bq_table_full_path = f"""{project_name}.{bq_dataset_name}.{bq_table_name}"""

    bq_client = bigquery.Client()

    query_string = """
    SELECT user_login  
    FROM `my_table_full_path`  
    WHERE DATE(insert_time) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY user_login
    """

    bq_response = bq_client.query(query_string)
    df = pd.DataFrame(bq_response)
    csv_data = df.to_csv(header=False, index=False)

    # create and upload file to Google Storage
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    file_name = 'daily_active_users_' + timestr + '.csv'
    upload_blob(data=csv_data, destination_blob_name=file_name)

    def upload_blob(data, destination_blob_name):
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(destination_bucket)
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
        blob.upload_from_string(data, 'text/csv')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use the export statement?

Comment: Can you share a logical example of this?

Comment: I wrote 2 articles on that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/get-a-single-one-csv-file-with-bigquery-export-956d2a147886 and https://medium.com/google-cloud/replicate-data-from-bigquery-to-cloud-sql-2b23a08c52b1 You can leverage Cloud Workflow to automate the task. It's serverless and codeless, therefore less expensive and much more scalable.

Comment: Hi @Gregof, try to replace `df = pd.DataFrame(bq_response)` to `df = bq_response.to_dataframe()` to return only the actual values of the column. The issue is on how you convert it to dataframe.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for sharing that! Definitely will be useful for my project. Thanks.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, regarding your proposed solution with workflow. I need a scheduling query every day, but it looks like your solution requires also a cloud function to be scheduled. So for my use case it is not more beneficial than current approach.

Comment: No, you can simply use a Cloud Scheduler that run directly a Workflow, no need an intermediary Cloud Functions for that. With the UI the configuration of Cloud Scheduler on a workflow is now easier. Remember, Cloud Scheduler can call any API, Cloud Functions or Google Cloud API, and you can execute a Workflow with a simple API call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the method `to_dataframe` of [QueryJob](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob) to return the dataframe.

Instead of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(bq_response)
```

Try this:

```
df = bq_response.to_dataframe()
```

Comment: now it works perfectly. Thank you! Yesterday I have the issue with pyarrow library in GCP so decided to use that workaround with `pd.DataFrame(bq_response)`. But now I just added `pyarrow` in my requirements.txt and now it works again.